# Discord.js v14 - Translating old Math.random() code for bot to change server icon periodically

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to translate/update some old `discord.js` code I typed up a very long time ago (maybe in 2017/18) for a `.js` bot I was practicing code on. Essentially, what it used to do was change the guild icon periodically on one server I owned. It used an `array` and `Math.random()`. Here is some of the code I think that could be salvageable:

```
function changeGuildIcon(guild) {
  var icons = new Array();

  icons[0] = "https://cdn.glitch.com/221cf221-9488-4246-bae1-269b2e87266f%2Fquack1.jpg?1546874576807";
  icons[1] = "https://cdn.glitch.com/221cf221-9488-4246-bae1-269b2e87266f%2Fquack2.png?1546874572153";
  icons[2] = "https://cdn.glitch.com/221cf221-9488-4246-bae1-269b2e87266f%2Fquack3.png?1546874572398";
  icons[3] = "https://cdn.glitch.com/221cf221-9488-4246-bae1-269b2e87266f%2Fquack4.png?1546874572493";
  icons[4] = "https://cdn.glitch.com/221cf221-9488-4246-bae1-269b2e87266f%2Fquack5.png?1546874573152";

  function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i; //var is important
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      x = a[i];
      a[i] = a[j];
      a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
  }

  var icons_shuffle = shuffle(icons);

  console.log(icons_shuffle);

  var iconsans = icons_shuffle[icons_shuffle.length - 1];
  icons_shuffle.pop();

  guild.setIcon(iconsans).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
}

client.on("ready", () => {
  let guild = client.guilds.get("242786073040781322");
  setInterval(
    changeGuildIcon,
    1000 /* < milliseconds */ * 60 /* < seconds */ * 60 /* < minutes */,
    guild
  );
});
```

I can't remember what version of discord.js I used for this however I had it written all in one long `main.js` file with many other commands split by `else if` statements.

How could I get this to work again automatically whilst my discord bot is online and what do I add before calling these functions to work as an event?

Any suggestions/resources would be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is actually wrong? Does it show an error, or not run at all?

Comment: @LarryTLlama I have't tried running it as i'm not sure on what to add just before calling the function. I've got practice in making slash commands, however i'm unsure about making a command activate automatically once my bot turns on.

Comment: If I run it with just `const client = require("../../index.js");`
It comes up with an error saying `TypeError: client.guilds.get is not a function`

Comment: Well, you'll need to look at creating a client (similar to your old code, however you need to look at [gateway intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents)). Looking at your code, I believe you also need to change the `client.guilds.get` to `client.guilds.cache.get()` since that is a recent API change.

Comment: @LarryTLlama seems like `client.guilds.cache.get()` along with gateway intents did the trick and it comes back with no errors, however it's only printing the array in the console and the icon itself isn't changing even if i switch it to 10 seconds.

Comment: Your shuffle function returns an array, so it should return that in the console. As for your icon changing, the code looks correct and up-to-date with the docs. I believe these changes aren't instantaneous, and will take a while to update on the client-side. Try restarting discord?

Comment: Thanks @LarryTLlama , a bit of troubleshooting and your input has made it work! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following `LarryTLlama`'s suggestions, I made the following additions & changes:

```
const client = require("../../index.js");
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

function changeGuildIcon(guild, interaction) {
  var icons = new Array();
```

**and**

```
  var icons_shuffle = shuffle(icons);

  //console.log(icons_shuffle);

  var iconsans = icons_shuffle[icons_shuffle.length - 1];
  icons_shuffle.pop();

  guild.setIcon(iconsans)/*.then(console.log).catch(console.error)*/;
}

client.on("ready", () => {
  let guild = client.guilds.cache.get("242786073040781322");
  setInterval(
    changeGuildIcon,
    1000 /* < milliseconds */ * 60 /* < seconds */ * 30 /* < minutes */,
    guild
  );
});
```

seemed to have done the trick. Thanks.